# remove a sprite in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos2d-x.I am developing a game in xcode using cocos2d-x. 
In my game, i have sprite animation(man) and moving obstacles and coins. I making collision with sprite animation & coins. When i get 10 coins, i am adding a life(adding a sprite for life).
My question is when collision is happening between sprite animation(man) & obstacles, life should decrease(i mean life sprite should remove) but it is not removed.
I am using the following code.

```
if(coincount%10==0)
{
  lifecount=lifecount+1;
}
if(lifecount==1)
{
 life = CCSprite::create("life.png");
 life->setPosition( ccp(winwsize/2, winhsize/1.08) );
 this->addChild(life, 5);
}
else if(lifecount==2)
{
 life1 = CCSprite::create("life.png");
 life1->setPosition( ccp(winwsize/1.8, winhsize/1.08) );
 this->addChild(life1, 5);
}
else if (lifecount==3)
{
 life2 = CCSprite::create("life.png");
 life2->setPosition( ccp(winwsize/1.6, winhsize/1.08) );
 this->addChild(life2, 5);
}

if (manRect.intersectsRect(obs5Rect))
{
if(lifecount>=1)
{
 lifecount=lifecount-1;
 this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(PlayScene::remove),0.5f);
}

void PlayScene::remove()
{
if(lifecount==0)
{
    this->removeChild(life, true);
}
else if(lifecount==1)
{
this->removeChild(life1, true);
}
else if(lifecount==2)
{
this->removeChild(life2, true);
}
```

But sprite is not removing, when obstacle collide with sprite animation(man).
Please anyone could help me to find the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to do:

```
life1->setTag(99); // i made up the 99
```

and then when you want to remove it use `removeChildByTag(99);`

Answer (score 2):

```
First setTag on Sprite like:
Sprite->setTag(111);
removeChildByTag(111);

       OR

Sprite->removeFromParent();
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the problem is in your `remove` function. You create sprites `life, life1, life2` when `lifeCount` is 1, 2 or 3 respectively. But in your remove method, you check if `lifeCount` is 0, 1 or 2. If it were 3, none of the sprites would be removed, as none of the conditions are met. Also you do not deacrease `lifeCount` anywhere.

Solution :
Either add `--lifecount;` at the beginning of `remove()`, or change your conditions appropriately and decrease the counter at the end.

Suggestions :
If I may suggest an improvemt to your code : you should keep your `life` sprites in an array, so that when you decide to add the possibility to have more lives it will be much easier.

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: I edited my question. I decrease lifecount=lifecount-1 before calling remove function.

Comment: Well, does this mean that this suggestion does not solve the problem? You can also try calling `life->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true)` instead of `this->removeChild(...)`